# error TS1312: Did you mean to use a ':'? An '=' can only follow a property name when the containing object literal is part of a destructuring pattern

Tags: angular, typescript

To be simple, I have some data below and I want to display it in the HTML.

```
MET:[
 {
    LABEL:"WILHELMSEN HLD ASA",
    ISINCODE:"NO0010571698",
    RECORD_DATE:"2022-09-16",
    EVENT_DATE:"2022-09-30",
    EVENT_TYPE:"AG Ordinaire",
    SOLDE:15000.00,
    NUMERO_AG:10642,
    CREAT_DATE:"2022-04-01",
    MOD_DATE:"2022-04-01",
    EMETTEUR:"408659",
    DEPOSITAIRE:"CA000005775300",
    ISCONFIRMED:1,
    ISSRD2ELIGIBLE:1,
    ADRESSE1:"Strandveien 20",
    ADRESSE2:"",
    LOCALITE:"LYSAKER",
    CODEPOSTAL:0,
    PAYS:"NOR",
    STATUTAG:9,
    URL:"",
    RESOLUTION:[
     {
       REF:"01",
     },
    ]
 }
],
```

I managed to display the data from the `MET` table.

Mais j'ai un problème avec la table `RESOLUTION`. dans la page service.ts

```
src/app/todo/todo.service.ts:31:20 - error TS1312: Did you mean to use a ':'? An '=' can 

only follow a property name when the containing object literal is part of a destructuring pattern.

31         RESOLUTION = [
```

I don't know what the problem is?

**todo.service**

```
export class TodoService {
  MET = [
    {
      LABEL: "WILHELMSEN",
      ISINCODE: "NO0010571698",
      RECORD_DATE: "2022-09-16",
      EVENT_DATE: "2022-09-30",
      EVENT_TYPE: "AG Ordinaire",
      SOLDE: 15000.0,
      NUMERO_AG: 10642,
      CREAT_DATE: "2022-04-01",
      MOD_DATE: "2022-04-01",
      EMETTEUR: "408659",
      DEPOSITAIRE: "CA000005775300",
      ISCONFIRMED: 1,
      ISSRD2ELIGIBLE: 1,
      ADRESSE1: "Strand 20",
      ADRESSE2: "",
      LOCALITE: "LYS",
      CODEPOSTAL: 0,
      PAYS: "NOR",
      STATUTAG: 9,
      URL: "",

      RESOLUTION = [
        {
          REF: "01",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}
}
```

**todo.component**

```
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  MET: any;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.MET = this.todoService.MET;
  }
}
```

todo.html

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="MET">
   <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>
   <table class="mb-5">
      <tr>
         <th>Isin</th>
         <th>Dénomination</th>
         <th>Date de création</th>
         <th>Date de modification</th>
         <th>Code d'identification</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>Réference du dépositaire</th>
         <th>Confirmé</th>
         <th>Eligible à SRD2</th>
         <th>Lieu de l'événement</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let line of MET">
         <td>{{ line.ISINCODE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.LABEL }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.CREAT_DATE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.MOD_DATE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.EMETTEUR}} </td>
         <td>{{ line.STATUTAG }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.DEPOSITAIRE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.ISCONFIRMED }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.ISSRD2ELIGIBLE }} </td>
         <td>{{ line.ADRESSE1 }} {{ line.LOCALITE}} </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: A the error message tells you, `RESOLUTION = [` should be `RESOLUTION: [`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```json
     RESOLUTION: [
        {
          REF: "01",
        },
      ],
```

instead of

```json
     RESOLUTION = [
        {
          REF: "01",
        },
      ],
```

because you can't assign stuff in a json